# Bootstrap 3 - Aligning column height

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, grid, alignment

create a site for educational purposes but I'm stuck with grid/column height issue.

Here's an image of site I'm trying to replicate:
[Click me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dge5f.jpg)

Here's what I've got so far: [Click me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WYqZJ.jpg)

My problem is, on the first row I have two columns (col-sm-6) and on the first column I nested another row and created 2 additional columns within it. However, the second columns seems to be taller than the first one. I tried to adjust the img size but it loses the responsiveness that I need.

Hope someone understood what I'm trying to say, I'm really new to web development. I hope someone can help me out. :(

Please refer to the images attached to verify issue. Thanks.

My code -

HTML:

```
    <!-- start portfolio-content -->
        <section class="portfolio-content">
            <div class="row" id="port-first-row">
                <div class="col-sm-6" id="port-first-col">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-12">
                            <img src="images/others/large/BridalPlannerHeader.jpg" alt="image"/>
                        </div> <!-- end col-12 -->
                        <div class="col-12">
                            <img src="images/others/large/video-home.jpg" alt="video" />
                        </div> <!-- end col-12 -->
                    </div> <!-- end row -->
                </div> <!-- end port-first-col -->

                <div class="col-sm-6" id="port-second-col">
                    <img src="images/home/medium/KC_phuket-thailand-wedding-photographer_0061.jpg" alt="image" />
                </div> <!--end port-second-col -->
            </div> <!-- end port-first-row -->

            <div class="row" id="port2-second-row">
                <div class="col-sm-6" id="port2-first-col">
                    <img src="images/others/large/Phuket_view.jpg" alt="phuket" />
                </div> <!-- end col-sm-6 -->
                <div class="col-sm-6" id="port2-second-col">
                    <img src="images/others/large/Julie+Andrew_darinimages-409.jpg" alt="julie" />
                </div> <!-- end col-sm-6 -->

            </div> <!-- end port-second-row -->
        </section> <!-- end portfolio-content -->
```

CSS/SASS:

```css
 .portfolio-content {
    max-width: 100%;
  }
  img {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .col-sm-6 {
    padding: 0;
  } 
  #port-first-row {
    max-width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
  }
  #port2-second-row {
    max-width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
  }
```

Comment: there's no `col-12` class in the bootstrap

Comment: try to use  bootstrap predefined `class="img-responsive"` for images.

Comment: I thought col-12 let's you use the whole length of a div or occupy all 12 spaces? Hmm. Let me try img-responsive once i get home. I'll get back to you bud, thanks for answering btw. :)

Comment: to fill whole width of row for any viewport width you can use `col-xs-12`

Comment: I see.. How about the img-responsive class? Would it work even if the div containing it has an undefined width/height? I'm eager to try it out but I'm not home yet. :(

Comment: Or I would have to define width/height then it would scale up/down accordingly?

Comment: EDIT/CHANGES:

Tried adding col-xs-12 instead of col-12, and it works better. However, both colums are still not the same height.

Is it possible for both div to follow it's containing div? I haven't actually defined height of containing div as it breaks it's responsiveness.

img-responsive class didn't do anything btw, maybe because I already have defined the img to have a: `width: 100%
height: auto`

Comment: do the images have equal dimensions or equal width/height ratio? Also to set responsive height you can use `vh` units.

Comment: img's doesn't have equal dimensions, first column img's are wider but shorter (960x480) while second column has taller img's (64x660). I got those on the actual site, do you think it has something to do with it?Or it's just just that my codes are messed up and wrong? Here's what I got so far, can't seem to work it out, column won't fill the containing div, been trying for days now. :( Kindly check link below:
http://s347.photobucket.com/user/Young_Do_Choi/media/helllp_zpsv272ffri.jpg.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a snippet, but I can't realize why are so huge gaps between columns.

Although look at https://jsfiddle.net/xeen9s7y/ - it works well.

I've added `border: solid 1px red;` to images for better visual control.

```css
img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border: solid 1px red;
}
.imgcont {
    height: 25vw;
    padding: 1px;
}
.imgcont2 {
    height: 50vw;
    padding: 1px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
      <section class="portfolio-content">
            <div class="row" id="port-first-row">
                <div class="col-xs-6" id="port-first-col">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-12 imgcont">
                            <img src="//placehold.it/200x150/2255EE" alt="image"/>
                        </div> <!-- end col-12 -->
                        <div class="col-xs-12 imgcont">
                            <img src="//placehold.it/200x150/2255EE" alt="video" />
                        </div> <!-- end col-12 -->
                    </div> <!-- end row -->
                </div> <!-- end port-first-col -->

                <div class="col-xs-6 imgcont2" id="port-second-col">
                    <img src="//placehold.it/200x150/2255EE" alt="image" />
                </div> <!--end port-second-col -->
            </div> <!-- end port-first-row -->

            <div class="row" id="port2-second-row">
                <div class="col-xs-6 imgcont" id="port2-first-col">
                    <img src="//placehold.it/200x150/2255EE" alt="phuket" />
                </div> <!-- end col-sm-6 -->
                <div class="col-xs-6 imgcont" id="port2-second-col">
                    <img src="//placehold.it/200x150/2255EE" alt="julie" />
                </div> <!-- end col-sm-6 -->

            </div> <!-- end port-second-row -->
        </section> <!-- end portfolio-content -->
```

Comment: Are you God?! LOL. Thanks man! You're a life saver! Now all I have to do is to understand how you did it. Or maybe you can give a quick explanation how it did the trick? It might solve another problem I have which is still regarding the grid, if it's not too much maybe you could look into it.
First and Second row's middle padding/margin doesn't align. Trying to solve it now.. But seriously, thanks man! You're awesome! :) 

Here:

http://photobucket.com/user/Young_Do_Choi/media/thanksman_zpsgwol9xuu.jpg.html

Comment: I got it aligned now! Thanks man! Here's the output: 
http://photobucket.com/user/Young_Do_Choi/media/WORKINGFINE_zpsvtn39yj7.jpg.html

I gotta know exactly how you did it man! You're genius! I love you for that! LOL! If you can explain it to me that would be really awesome! But either way, I really can't thank you enough, bud.BIG THANKS!!!!!

Comment: `padding: 1px;` overrides BS's default settings of padding. if you'll remove `padding: 1px;` from styles you will see the defaults, which are `padding-right: 15px; padding-left: 15px;` , also padding-top and padding-bottom are  zero by default.

Comment: Right right, but I think what helped me the most was the 'vw' attribute, I believe that's Viewport Width, correct? I gotta look into it more coz' I'm kinda confused how to use it effectively. I mean, you used 'vw' to define height instead of 'vh' which worked wonders but confusing, at least for my level that is.

Comment: I use `vw` often for height definition. it works when your outer container (for your case it is `section`) fills whole screen width. If it doesn't, then you need to calculate cell height with javascript

Comment: I guess it's a good practice, I'll use it often then. :) What I usually do to get better at coding is converting psd files to html5, or try to replicate an actual website like the project you helped me with. If by any chance you have some good resources to master front end web development please let me know. I'd really appreciate it. :)

Comment: It is not always enough time to read tons of articles. Therefore  the best way to raise my skills for me is reading of HTML and CSS official specifications and immediate implementation new knowledge through experimental coding practice.

Comment: I see. Well then, you've been really helpful, like seriously the best, man. My deepest gratitude to you. :) I would probably post/ask something again, hope you'll be there to help me out. Cheers to you, buddy! And Happy Holidays too! :)